# iis and asp.net mvc compilation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

as project is in developing state uploaded Files on webserver has not been compiled for easy editing and other reason , when i edit `model` and add `property` to `view` , `iis` say that your model has no that because of old compilation files , solution that Tested :

1. Deleted Temp folder in `windows\microsoft.net`
2. `<compilation batch="false" debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />`
3. add new line to `webconfig`  to force new compile

yet it run old compiled files

Comment: Are you saying you're editing the files that **have been deployed**?

Comment: yes , edit files on `webserver`

Comment: Step Away From The Server..!!! :)  You are asking for trouble doing this.  How are you keeping the Dev copy and Production copy in Sync?

Comment: copy of source code,  has been uploaded , then change model in local and upload just model that has been modded . both dev copy and production file are same .

Comment: Are you publishing the application? or just taking the source code from the folder and dropping it on the server?

Comment: just taking the source code from the folder and dropping it on the server as mentioned in question !

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments, I will add an answer...

You need to actually `publish` the application: [How to publish a web app](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20yh9f1b%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).  You can publish this locally on your desktop and copy the files onto the server, or you can publish direct to your server.

When you publish the application, the `model(s)` get compiled into an `assembly` in your `bin` folder, so you cant directly modify these files on the fly.

You can chose a setting to allow for views to be updated, but this is very limited.

So, best approach is to set up a [publish profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398069.aspx) for your DEV server, and make your change, and then re-publish.  It will take you less than a minute to get the latest code on the server.